# I am creating a page which involves creating a new html table every time depending on the selected option ,how to go about it?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am creating a page which involves creating a new  html table on the same page every time depending on the selected option. On the option being selected, the user submit the details.The data is  fetched using Jquery,ajax and php.After the data is received,it is made into the table form using Datatable API.I have created the table for the first option ,but I am getting stuck and confused on how to proceed about the rest of the select options from the dropdown.Please suggest soemthing.I have researched enough but most of the results involve adding new row to a table.

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{     


 $('#selectInfo').on('change',function(){
  if(this.value == 2){
   arr2=["User ID","Policy Name","Profile ID", "Profile Name"];

// First create your thead section
$('#tab').append('<thead><tr></tr></thead>');

// Then create your head elements
$thead = $('#displayTab > #tab > thead > tr:first');
for (var i = 0, len = arr2.length; i < len; i++) {
 $thead.append('<th>'+arr2[i]+'</th>');
}
}


});


 $('#dashboard').submit(function(e)
 { 
  e.preventDefault();
  var datastring = $('#dashboard').serialize();

  $.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url:'dashboard.php',
   dataType:"json",
   data: datastring,

   success: function(response)
   {
         
                   








                    $.each(response,function(key,value){
                     var body = "<tr>";
                     body += "<td>"+value.device_id+"</td>";
                     body += "<td>"+value.email+"</td>";
                     body += "<td>"+value.city+"</td>";
                     body += "<td>"+value.first_name+"</td>";
                     body += "<td>"+value.address+"</td>";
                     body += "<td>"+value.branch_head+"</td>";
                     body += "<td>"+value.branch_mobile_no+"</td>";
                     body += "<td>"+value.office_head+"</td>";
                     body += "<td>"+value.office_mobile_no+"</td>";
                     body += "<td>"+value.location_of_sbk+"</td>";
                     body += "</tr>";
                     $("#tab tbody").append(body);  
                    });

                    $("#tab").DataTable();
            //});   
            $('#tab').removeClass('display').addClass('table table-hover table compact');
            
            console.log(response);
            
        },

        error: function(response)
        {
         alert(response);
        }

    });
 });



});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Dashboard</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css">

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap-datepicker-master/dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="DataTables/datatables.min.css"/>


</head>
<body>
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Dashboard</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
   <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
   <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link" href="/Analytics/analytical.html">Analytics</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link" href="#">Export Info</a>
    </li> 
   </ul>
  </div>
 </nav> 

 <form method="POST" style="margin: 0 auto;" id="dashboard">
  <div class="form-group" style="display: inline-block;">
   <label for="inputInfo">Select Information:</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="selectInfo" name="info">
     <option value="1">Register Device</option>
     <option value="2">Device Assign policies</option>
     <option value="3">Device Patch History</option>
     <option value="4">Battery Information</option>
     <option value="5">Network Status</option>
     <option value="6">Device Status</option>
     <option value="7">App status</option>
    </select>
   </div>

  <div class="form-group" style="display: inline-block;">
   <label for="inputFrom"> From: </label>
   <div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker" id="datepicker1" >
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="from">
    <div class="input-group-addon">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
    </div>
   </div>

  </div>
         
         <div class="form-group" style="display: inline-block;">
   <label for="inputFrom"> To: </label>
   <div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker" id="datepicker2" >
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="to">
    <div class="input-group-addon">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
    </div>
   </div>

  </div>

  <div class="form-group" style="display: inline-block;">
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
 </form>


 <div id="displayTab">
  <table id="tab" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%" >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Device ID</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Branch Venue</th>
            <th>Branch Circle</th>
            <th>Branch Address</th>
            <th>Branch Head</th>
            <th>Office Mobile No</th>
            <th>OPS Head</th>
            <th>Mobile No</th>
            <th>Location</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     
    </tbody>

  </table>
  
 </div>

    <script >
     $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#datepicker1').datepicker({
       format: 'd-m-y'
      });
      $('#datepicker2').datepicker({
                format: 'd-m-y'
      });

     });
    </script>



 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap-datepicker-master/dist/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="dashboard.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="DataTables/datatables.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: _I have researched enough..._ I don't think your research was enough since you don't have your answer..... Please **visit** the **[help center](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)** and take the tour to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post codes and efforts!

Comment: What have you tried? Where is your code? Stackoverflow is not a coding service.

Comment: I am not asking for the full code ,I am just asking for the approach.Notice I said "Please suggest something".I am stuck that's why i asked.If you could waste your time preaching here, I might as well choose to break my head googling and researching.Also,I am relatively new to stack overflow in posting questions.

Comment: ` how to proceed about the rest of the select options from the dropdown` - what do you mean ? Could you please explain in other words or provide full explanation with code, screens etc

Comment: Seems like you just copy and paste code. Go read a little bit more before begin with the projects.

Comment: All I wanted was a little help and what i received was condescending behaviour.I am a beginner in jquery,php,javascript actually.,won't  make the mistake of asking here.

Comment: @shreyanshshekhar There are some rules which everyone have to follow in their question. Your question is not according to SO rules. Please edit your question and only post relevant code not all of your coding files :)
I hope it makes sense to you and don't be disheartened, in the beginning I have also gone through this. It takes time to learn using stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, you wrote api handler for option number 2: "Device Assign policies".
Then, handler returns json response which converts to the table and appends to the body.

Next, as I got, you need to handle other options from select. And those options also are related to the same table from previous response.

So, by clicking on any option you need: retrieve some json data from api handler and redraw the table.

For such purpose you need:

1) Inintialize some frontend table from empty response on page load: 
`

```
function drawTableFromResponse(response) {
    var body = '';
    $.each(response.header,function(key,value){
           body += '<thead><tr></tr></thead>';
           // draw table header from response
    }

    $.each(response.body,function(key,value){
           body += "<tr>";
           body += "<td>"+value.device_id+"</td>";
           ...
           ...
           body += "</tr>";
           // draw table body from response
       });

       $("#tab tbody").append(body);
       $("#tab").DataTable();
}

drawTableFromResponse({header: [], body: []});
```

`

2) on option changing and submitting the form - you will retrieve new response and redraw the table:

```
$('#dashboard').submit(function(e) {
    .....
    .....
    .....

    success: function(response) {
        drawTableFromResponse(response);
    }
});
```

3) That's all you need in JS. Rest of logic (check which option was clicked, combine header/body columns etc.) should be in your api handler: `dashboard.php`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is enough!Yeah ,i am handling the logic in the api handler,I am clear with that .I was just stuck with creating the tables dynamically.Thanks again!